# How to display Kendo grid dropdown column always in edit mode?

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo grid which has column Action as Dropdown. Its working fine.
But the behavior is when grid load the dropdown column value display as text and when I click on that text then dropdown get display with populated values.
Is it possible to display column value always in Dropdown instead of Text?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some code that for you doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a sample on how to do it for a checkbox: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/Templates/grid-with-checkbox-column

I Guess you could do the same for a drop-down:

- Create a template for the column with a drop-down.
- Add a javascript which updates the underlying model when the user change the selected item in the drop-down.